# SEO Optimisation: 1.1/2" - One-and-a-Half Inch - 1.5 Inch - 1.5" ? What should I use?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines

**TLDR: What is the best way to write this for SEO purposes?**

As mentioned in the title, I have some products with different sizes that I want to make sure the SEO is

My particular concern is with inch type measurements

There are many ways of writing the same thing:

I have chosen 1.1/2" as an example, but this is a general problem

```
1.1/2"
1.5"
1.1/2&Prime; // written this out so it is visibly different
1-1/2"
one-and-a-half-inch
1.1/2 inch
1.5 inch
etc...
```

`&Prime;` is the correct abbreviation, but I imagine less than 1% of people even know of its existance, probably Google doesn't take much interest in it... "Correct" and "Best" are not always the same. In this scenario I am looking for the "Best" only, from a SEO perspective

Specifically for page titles and page URLs which will have dash-separated words generally

Another consideration is that "/" will not be ideal in a URL, but I guess written in full one-and-a-half-inch would be optimal for URLs.

Comment: Google is pretty good at handling synonyms, and 1.5 compared to 1½ is pretty straightforward for it. Of course, you could just go for 38.1mm.

Comment: thanks- I take your suggestion for mm, but I am concerned that many who search for inches would not use the equivalent mm values, also since there can be metric sizes too it might confuse. I feel like the most human way to type into google search would be 1.5" ?

Comment: @user16861522 - Then, thats how you should do it.

Comment: There is no official guidance on this then? Or unofficial test data? Just want to make sure it is optimal that is all